# get certain data from json golang

Tags: json, go

```
tmpbyte, _ := json.Marshal(vdata["user"])

fmt.Println(string(tmpbyte))
```

I got this data from mongodb,

```
[
  {
    "avatar_image": "https://i6e.jpg",
    "display_name": "flash.info",
    "image_user": "",
    "user_id": "qXGFIa",
    "username": "flash.info"
  },
  {
    "avatar_image": "https://847a",
    "display_name": "Akhmad Jazuli",
    "image_user": "",
    "user_id": "mf7EXj",
    "username": "akhmad.jazuli"
  },
  {
    "avatar_image": "https://i-stageb10a.jpg",
    "display_name": " Alfan Rey",
    "image_user": "",
    "user_id": "bsiAlG",
    "username": "fn.alfan"
  }
]
```

how to get only loop of user_id from this data?

user_id1
user_id2
user_id1

Comment: is your `vdata` a map or interface?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create a data structure for your entities about users and then decode the data using MongoDB.

```golang
type User struct {
    Id          primitive.ObjectID `bson="_id"`
    AvatarImage string             `bson="avatar_image"`
    DisplayName string             `bson="display_name"`
    UserId      string             `bson="user_id"`
    UserName    string             `bson="username"`
}

func GetUserIds(ctx context.Context) ([]string, error) {
    userIds := make([]string, 0)
    cur, err := collectionUser.Find(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        user := new(User)
        if err := cur.Decode(user); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        
        userIds = append(userIds, user.UserId)
    }
    
    return userIds, nil
}

}
```